# How to calculate daily sales with vb.net and sql

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to sum the Amount in my Bill Table via dates and report as daily sales

The table columns are
Client Name, Amount, BDate
This is what I have tried

```
   Dim query = "SELECT SUM(Amount)as sales FROM BillTbl where [BDate] = ? "
        Dim conkey As New SqlConnection(con)
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand(query, conkey)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BDate", Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))

        conkey.Open()
        Dim total As Double = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        check.Text = total.ToString
        conkey.Close()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to pass a string for a date? Is a date. Would you convert a number to a string if you wanted to filter by a number? I doubt it.

Comment: You need to provide far more detail about exactly what you are trying to achieve and exactly what happens when you use the code you have and how that doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: Use **named parameters** with SqlClient instead of `?` placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the type of the `BDate` is `Date` or `DateTime` and **NOT** `varchar` (which would be **very bad**):

```
Dim query = "SELECT SUM(Amount)as sales FROM BillTbl where [BDate] = cast(current_timestamp as Date)"

Using conkey As New SqlConnection(con), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)

    conkey.Open()
    Dim total As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
```

I also wanted to talk about query parameters, but as you can see there is no need for any parameter in the above code at all; the database has its own way to get the current time. So instead I'll add another example to show the right way to use a (now unnecessary) parameter:

```
Dim query = "SELECT SUM(Amount)as sales FROM BillTbl where [BDate] = @BDate"

Using conkey As New SqlConnection(con), _
      cmd As New SqlCommand(query, con)

    ' Always choose an SqlDbType and Length to match the database column
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Today
    conkey.Open()
    Dim total As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
End Using
```

Notice the parameter placeholder in the query has a name that matches what we use later on. Also notice we gave the parameter an explicit type. There is a problem with `AddWithValue()` that can result in major performance issues. Another change is replacing `.Close()` with a `Using` block, which is safer. The `.Close()` code might never run if there is an exception with a query, but the `Using` block will still  close the connection. Additionally, note we never converted the date value to a string. If you ever find yourself converting a date to a string for use in SQL, something has gone very wrong, and especially the `MM/dd/yyyy` format from the question is *not correct* for SQL.

Finally, note the `total` variable in both these examples goes out of scope immediately after the code block is done. You may need to declare the variable earlier in the scope to give it a larger scope, and then merely set the value at this time.